# Почему бы не показывать когда репутация снизилась?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, репутация

Почему ни на одном сайте сети мы не показываем, когда репутация снизилась? Ведь если участник точно не помнит сколько у него было репутации вчера, а сегодня он получил минус, он даже не будет об этом знать, если только не кликнет на кубок. Я считаю, что такое надо добавить. Если же были получены и минусы, и плюсы, то надо брать набранную репутацию - потерянную, и в зависимости от сравнения с нулем высвечивать. Вот мое предложение.

> [image]

Comment: _надо высвечивать набранную репутацию - потерянную_ - это уже так.

Comment: А если [-670](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45057148#45057148) будет, как предлагаете отображать?

Comment: @АндрейNOP -2 от -670 концептуально не отличаются никак.

Comment: @АндрейNOP так же, как и +670, только с минусом?)

Comment: @andreymal, ок.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Идея не нова. Вот соответствующий feature request на MSE: [Display lost/negative reputation in topbar achievements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208900/339911)

И как можно заметить, при большом количестве голосов «за» (сейчас там +145/-7) предложение помечено меткой [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined). Как указано в одном из ответов, это второй по популярности FR, отклоненный руководством Stack Exchange. Выводы делайте сами. Но вряд ли эту идею будут пересматривать в ближайшее время.

Comment: Демотивирующий бейдж, поэтому не хотят добавлять

Comment: @АндрейNOP или наоборот, мотивирующий исправлять заминусованные ошибки.

Comment: Очень жаль, что не хотят реализовать. Хорошая была бы вещь.

Comment: @Dima мы может представить, что люди, которые это решение приняли не являются идиотами и у них была какая-то мотивация, чтобы первоначально ввести текущее поведение и позже отклонить популярный запрос об его отмене¶ Подробного объяснения я не встречал. Могу только догадываться на основе данных в разнице поведения  людей, которые получают хвалу или критику (подсказка: одно более эффективней чем другое в широком наборе обстоятельств).

Comment: @jfs, возможно, у них была веская причина, согласен. Мне лично бывает не всегда понятно, почему репутация снизилась. Час назад была Х, теперь уже Х-У. А все почему? Просто кто-то "минусанул вопрос/ответ". Чтобы узнать объем изменений приходится выполнять лишние телодвижения - открывать окошко изменения репутации. Поэтому лично для себя я "оставляю" уведомление о последнем положительном изменении репутации, чтобы после снижения репутации сопоставить значение "до" и "после". Например, было "+4", а через час стало "+2". Значит, получил минус!)) Жаль, что нельзя сделать подобную вещь опциональной.

Comment: @Dima: дополнительно (не имеет отношения к аргументации выше): на своём опыте могу сказать, что крайне редко минусы вообще являются действительной критикой, поэтому вы вероятно много не теряете, если не сразу о них узнаёте, а только нажав на оповещения (это не к тому, что я ошибок не совершаю -- совершаю как и все другие люди, к тому, что эти ошибки редко минусами обнаруживаются -- чаще минус или случайность (не туда нажал) или месть (эмоции кого-то обуяли))

Comment: @jfs я тут человек новый (не во временнОм смысле,а в плане активного участия), так что мне очень важно знать, что репутация "скачет": если минус поставлен моему ответу, значит (высока вероятность) там будет комментарий с указанием того, что я неправильно сделал, а это возможность исправить ошибку и получить для себя новые знания. Опять же, сколько людей, столько и мнений. Но задумка интересная, я бы за нее проголосовал. Но ладно, нет такой возможности - и нет))

Comment: @Dima если вам оповещения о новых комментариях не приходят,  то это никак не связано с текущим вопросом. Стоит отдельное обсуждение начать, если это произойдёт.

Comment: @jfs, вчитайтесь, пожалуйста, в мой последний комментарий. Я не говорил про отсутствие оповещений о новых комментариях. Всего лишь пояснил, *почему лично мне* интересна фича об уведомлении о *понижении* репутации. Уведомления о комментариях мне приходят исправно.

Comment: @Dima: вы не поняли мой комментарий. Прямая цитата: *"там будет комментарий с указанием того, что я неправильно сделал, а это возможность исправить ошибку и получить для себя новые знания"*  -- ничто вам не мешает и сейчас этот комментарий прочитать.

Comment: @jfs вернул недавно уведомления в мобильном приложении, а теперь (после диалога в комментах) вспомнил, почему отключал. Видимо, пора опять это сделать.

Comment: @jfs, Вы выдернули цитату из контекста. Вот настоящее начало цитаты: *если минус поставлен моему ответу, значит (**высока вероятность**) там будет комментарий <...> новые знания*. Обратите внимание на текст, выделенный полужирным шрифтом. Однако зачастую негативная оценка не сопровождается комментарием, поэтому уведомление о снижении репутации было бы очень кстати, *как по мне*.

Comment: @alexolut, прошу прощения за разговоры под Вашим ответом ;) Мы с товарищем *jfs* уже все выяснили по поводу темы вопроса.

Comment: @Dima ещё раз: ничто не мешает вам сейчас комментарий прочитать. Уведомление о комментариях никак не связано с голосами.

Comment: @jfs давайте закончим это обсуждение? Или перейдем в чат? Вы, видимо не понимаете меня или не хотите понимать. Я одобряю уведомление о снижении репутации. О проблемах с комментариями я не сказал ни слова. Вот Вы, к примеру, можете сейчас "минусануть" любой из моих вопросов/ответов, а я и не узнаю об этом, пока не зайду на страницу своего профиля. Понимаете? А если Вы не просто снизите оценку, но также и напишите комментарий, тогда будет уведомление о комментарии, что позволит *также* узнать о снижении репутации путем "перехода" по ссылке на комментарий.

Comment: @älёxölüt вот вам ещё одна буква с точками: ẍ

Comment: @NickVolynkin спасибо, конечно, но откуда она у вас?

Comment: @älёxölüt собрал из `¨` (https://unicode-table.com/en/00A8/) и `x`. А вот `t` и `l` так не комбинируются.

Comment: @älёxölüt зато вот есть `ŀ`.